# populating checkbox using dynamic array in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can i pass a dynamic variable to selection for my ng-model of checkbox. Here is the the jsfiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/PQvQ2/

Here i want to replace the id in .js file with a variable as:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.categories = [ { "name": "Sport", "id": "50d5ad" } , {"name": "General", "id": "678ffr" } ];

    var someId = $scope.categories[1].id;
    $scope.selection = {
        ids: {someId: true}
    };
}
```

But it is not working. If i replace "someId" with "General", it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use object properties in two ways

`object.property1` or `object[property1]`

both will produce same result, so if you chage your js file to this,

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.categories = [{
        "name": "Sport",
        "id": "50d5ad"
    }, {
        "name": "General",
        "id": "678ffr"
    }];

    //define selection object
    $scope.selection = {ids : {}};

    angular.forEach($scope.categories, function(category){
        $scope.selection.ids[category.id] = true;
    });

}
```

it will give you to right result here is update [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wickY26/PQvQ2/336/)...

Comment: @tanuj you are welcome... please accept it as answer and upvote if it solves your problem, otherwise tell me and I try to help you further...